# Como generar un api key en Dglobal ID

Tags: api

estoy intentando generar un api key en Dglobal ID para poder conectar con mi cuenta y así permitir a mis usuarios registrarse con Dglobal ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para generar un api key con Dglobal tienes que visitar id.dglobal.dev iniciar sesión con tu cuenta o crear una nueva y visitar tu página de desarrollador ahí tienes que ir a "Developer options" y generar tu api key.

Espero que haya resuelto tu duda.